# Retrieve number from string via JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to retrieve a certain number from a string. But i can't figure out how to isolate the part i need.

The string:

```
https://intra.site.com/departments/travel/Lists/Booking/fd_Item_Display.aspx?List=8af14ed7-3bde-4ec0-b62a-9516324c967e&ID=15&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fintra%2Emonjasa%2Ecom%2Fdepartments%2Ftravel%2FPages%2Fdefault%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0100B7DC1AFF519B6343BC8014EB1910DFAB
```

I need the number after `ID=`.

I did try to use `string.replace()` without luck.

How could I do this with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str = 'https://intra.site.com/departments/travel/Lists/Booking/fd_Item_Display.aspx?List=8af14ed7-3bde-4ec0-b62a-9516324c967e&ID=15&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fintra%2Emonjasa%2Ecom%2Fdepartments%2Ftravel%2FPages%2Fdefault%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0100B7DC1AFF519B6343BC8014EB1910DFAB';
var id = (str.match(/&ID=([^&]*)/i) || ['', ''])[1];
//=> 15
```

Comment: Thx m8 - this works perfectly. I will mark as correct answer in 10 min.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out :

```
function getParameterByName(url, parameter) {
   var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + parameter + "=([^&#]*)"),
   results = regex.exec(url);
   return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var url = 'https://intra.site.com/departments/travel/Lists/Booking/fd_Item_Display.aspx?List=8af14ed7-3bde-4ec0-b62a-9516324c967e&ID=15&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fintra%2Emonjasa%2Ecom%2Fdepartments%2Ftravel%2FPages%2Fdefault%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0100B7DC1AFF519B6343BC8014EB1910DFAB';
var parameter = 'ID';

console.log( getParameterByName(url, parameter) );
// Log => 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Easier to understand.

```js
    

    function getID()
    {
      
    var str = "https://intra.site.com/departments/travel/Lists/Booking/fd_Item_Display.aspx?List=8af14ed7-3bde-4ec0-b62a-9516324c967e&ID=15&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fintra%2Emonjasa%2Ecom%2Fdepartments%2Ftravel%2FPages%2Fdefault%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0100B7DC1AFF519B6343BC8014EB1910DFAB";

    var id = str.match(/ID=(\d*)/)[1];        
     
    alert(id);
      
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="getID()" value="Click me">
```